# What is the difference between atomic code and critical code in multi threading?

Tags: synchronization

What is the difference between atomic code and critical code in multi threading? as far as I understand both should be code blocks that have to be executed by one thread at a time, but I didn't understand the depth of the meaning "critical" & "atomic".

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference. A critical *section* of code performs an atomic *operation*.

I don't know the histories of the two names.  I think maybe "critical section" came from operating system design, where it is sometimes important to disable interrupts during execution of certain sections of code; But I strongly prefer to say "atomic" because, for me anyway, it seems more obvious that I am describing a *sequence* of operations done by one thread that must be made to appear as if they happened in a single instant when seen by other threads.

Let's not forget that "operation" means operation on *data*. Code is read-only. Code never needs protection. It's always the data that needs protection.  If you think that some operation on a collection of data needs to be atomic, then you should ask whether other operations on the same data might also need to be atomic.